# R behavior of mutate and rnorm

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have the following code from a course

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data("polls_us_election_2016")
head(results_us_election_2016)

results_us_election_2016 %>% arrange(desc(electoral_votes)) %>% top_n(5, electoral_votes)

'Computing the average and standard deviation for each state'

polls <- polls_us_election_2016 %>%
  filter(state != "U.S." &
           !grepl("CD", "state") &
           enddate >= "2016-10-31" &
           (grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+") | is.na(grade))) %>%
  mutate(spread = rawpoll_clinton/100 - rawpoll_trump/100) %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(spread), sd = sd(spread), n = n()) %>%
  mutate(state = as.character(state))
# joining electoral college votes and results
results <- left_join(polls, results_us_election_2016, by="state")
head(results)

# states with no polls: note Rhode Island and District of Columbia = Democrat
results_us_election_2016 %>% filter(!state %in% results$state)

# assigns sd to states with just one poll as median of other sd values
results <- results %>%
  mutate(sd = ifelse(is.na(sd), median(results$sd, na.rm = TRUE), sd))

#Calculating the posterior mean and posterior standard error

mu <- 0
tau <- 0.02
results %>% mutate(sigma = sd/sqrt(n),
                   B = sigma^2/ (sigma^2 + tau^2),
                   posterior_mean = B*mu + (1-B)*avg,
                   posterior_se = sqrt( 1 / (1/sigma^2 + 1/tau^2))) %>%
  arrange(abs(posterior_mean))

#Monte Carlo simulation of Election Night results (no general bias)

mu <- 0
tau <- 0.02
clinton_EV <- replicate(1000, {
  results %>% mutate(sigma = sd/sqrt(n),
                     B = sigma^2/ (sigma^2 + tau^2),
                     posterior_mean = B*mu + (1-B)*avg,
                     posterior_se = sqrt( 1 / (1/sigma^2 + 1/tau^2)),
                     simulated_result = rnorm(length(posterior_mean), posterior_mean, posterior_se),
                     clintonvotes = ifelse(simulated_result > 0, electoral_votes, 0)) %>%    # award votes if Clinton wins state
    summarize(clinton = sum(clintonvotes)) %>%    # total votes for Clinton
    .$clinton + 7    # 7 votes for Rhode Island and DC
})
mean(clinton_EV > 269)    # over 269 votes wins election
```

I don't understand how this line works

```
simulated_result = rnorm(length(posterior_mean), posterior_mean, posterior_se)
```

`length(posterior_mean) = 47`, so `rnorm` should return a vector of size 47.
When I replace this with 1 each state gets the same result from rnorm although posterior_mean and posterior_se are diffent for each state. When I change it 46 I get an error.
So it seems to me that this line fills the whole column simulated_result (perhaps 47 times with the same results?). I would have expected that mutate uses the values of each row only to manipulate this particulate row.

Can perhaps someone explain this behavior to me or point me to a resource where this is explained?

Comment: Maybe `posterior_mean` is different for every state but `length(posterior_mean)` is the same value?

Comment: Incidentally, the following web application for experimental data simulation may be useful in the present context: https://github.com/pablobernabeu/Experimental-data-simulation

Answer (score 2):

For the `rnorm` function, if you check the vignette:

```
rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) Arguments

x, q    :vector of quantiles. 
p   :vector of probabilities. 
n   :number of observations. If length(n) > 1, the length is taken to be the number required. 
mean    :vector of means. 
sd  :vector of standard deviations.
```

There are two ways to use it, one, you generate a vector of length n, coming from normal distribution of same mean and sd, for example:

```
set.seed(111)
rnorm(10,0,1) 
 [1]  0.2352207 -0.3307359 -0.3116238 -2.3023457 -0.1708760  0.1402782 -1.4974267 -1.0101884
 [9] -0.9484756 -0.4939622
```

If you provide a vector that is as long as n, you are specifying the mean and sd for each entry, for example:

```
set.seed(111)
rnorm(10,1:10,1:10)
 [1]  1.23522071  1.33852826  2.06512853 -5.20938263  4.14561978  6.84166935 -3.48198659 -0.08150735
 [9]  0.46371956  5.06037783
```

In this case, you generate a vector of 10 random normal variable, first entry comes from mean=1, sd=1, 2nd entry mean=2, sd=2 and so on. We can also do something in between:

```
set.seed(111)
rnorm(10,1:10,1))
[1] 1.235221 1.669264 2.688376 1.697654 4.829124 6.140278 5.502573 6.989812 8.051524 9.506038
```

In this case, it returns a vector of length 10, first entry coming from mean = 1,sd=1, 2nd coming from mean =2,sd =1, and we can visualize this by re-running this:

```
t(replicate(10,rnorm(10,1:10,1)))
```

[image]

It's not very clear what you replaced with 1, but essentially the purpose of mutate is to assign a column with the values. And the simulated results columns work like the above.